# Google Sheet one column "fixed, rest tranpose

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I am trying to make the following without using google-script.

I have this sheet (A):

[image: The data I have]

And I want to get Sheet (B) "auto-updated", every time the sheet (A) changes.

What I am trying to get on sheet (B):

[image]

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I have a sort of method for this that I developed that I could demonstrate if you share a sample sheet.  It is a single formula and will handle very large datasets.

Comment: You can use textjoin, split and transpose

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing a sheet.  This formula is in A2 on a new tab called MK.Help.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(COUNTA('sheet 1'!A2:A)*4;1;0)/4+2;{ROW('sheet 1'!A2:A)\'sheet 1'!A2:A\'sheet 1'!B2:E\IF(ROW('sheet 1'!A2:A);'sheet 1'!B1:E1)};MOD(SEQUENCE(COUNTA('sheet 1'!A2:A)*4;1;0);4)*{0\1\1}+{2\3+4\3}))
```

This solution is designed for 4 columns.  In your case, there are no empty cells, but if there were, you would use a query around the solution like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(COUNTA('sheet 1'!A2:A)*4;1;0)/4+2;{ROW('sheet 1'!A2:A)\'sheet 1'!A2:A\'sheet 1'!B2:E\IF(ROW('sheet 1'!A2:A);'sheet 1'!B1:E1)};MOD(SEQUENCE(COUNTA('sheet 1'!A2:A)*4;1;0);4)*{0\1\1}+{2\3+4\3});"where Col2 is not null"))
```

It can also be built for an unknown number of columns.  If that's something you need, let me know.

I call this a "retabulation" problem and it comes up often enough that i tried to create a lesson for my method.  Here's a link to that lesson.  It's a bit of a work in progress, but maybe it will help.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EV_iziWtrTrkPdwY0FI2l0lzTFt-IRQHCOg1punnN5c/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

[image]

here the formula:

```
= arrayformula(
    {
      "Date","Country","Value";
      split 
      (
        transpose
        (
          split
          (
            textjoin
            (
              ":",false,filter(A2:A&","&B1:D1&"," & B2:D,A2:A<>"")
            )
            ,":",true,false
          )
        )
        ,",",true,false
      )
    }
  )
```